# Is it possible to configure a Castle Dynamic Proxy with Instance method of the WindsorContainer?

Tags: castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

... or does Castle need to have control over the construction process in order to wrap the object with the proxy?

I've tried a few different configurations - below is the one that I'm currently using, but the Interceptor is not being applied when I make a request for the object:

```
container.Kernel.Register(Component.For<IMyService>()
            .Instance(myService)
            .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<MyServiceProxy>()).Last,
        Component.For<MyServiceProxy>()
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the default `InstanceActivator` does not support proxying.